# Not able to read below JSON using Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I was not able to read below mentioned received **JSON** from Rest API.

```
{
    "details": {
        "id": 21,
        "gstin": "27AACCG7831Q1Z0",
        "entityName": "GENX ENTERTAINMENT LIMITED",
        "entityPan": "AACCG7831Q",
        "entityTan": "abhishek123",
        "entityCin": "null",
        "entityWebsite": null,
        "natureOfBusiness": null,
        "constitution": "\"Public Limited Company\""
    },
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 22,
            "buildingName": "\"Solitaire Corporate Park\"",
            "location": null,
            "street": null,
            "buildingNo": "\"S-14\"",
            "state": "bihar",
            "district": "\"\"",
            "city": "\"\"",
            "flateNo": "\"1\"",
            "pincode": "\"400093\"",
            "isPrimary": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to use above data received in JSON format into a form.

Comment: how do you read that json? - show code

Comment: What do you mean by 'read' the json? You want to use it in a html form or do what? better if you can specify what you actually need to do

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but you can pass this values to a form using this :

```
const formValues = JSON.parse(yourJson);
this.form.values = formValues;
```

Answer (score 0):

See The Stakblitz Code Below

[stackblit_sampleCode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/q23)

Hope this helps..!